# Junit5 AssertEquals is giving me wrong values.

Tags: java, testing, assert, junit5

When I'm doing assert equals i'm getting this and not 
the actual values of the calss.

assertEquals(expected, actual);

```
Actual: [com.eduardo.test.output@f58d94c2]
Expected: [{result={name="eduardo"}}]
```

Why is my object not getting recognized?

Comment: Could you provide actual and expected values, please?

BTW, actual type doesn't override toString() method.

Comment: Have you overridden the `equals` (and `hashCode`, and `toString`) method in your class?

Comment: Don't put "solved" in your title.  You can answer your own question by submitting an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an object. Which is what your method returns. You can either cast it to the type of the object you want, or assert the property.

something like assertThat(result.name = expectedName)

but I recommend you to use Pojomatic... 
You can use the annotation @AutoProperty on your object 
and include this method:

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return Pojomatic.equals(this, obj);
  }
```

that way your assert will work

Answer (score -1):

In my Object Mapper I added:

```
mapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES);
```

In my constructor I had to add: public

```
dummyClass(@JsonProperty("chargeType") String name)
    {
        this.name= name;

    }
```

This Solved my issue.